# Create a list of objects with initialized properties from a string with infos

Tags: c#, string, list, class, object

I have a string that looks like that:

```
random text 12234
another random text 

User infos: 

User name : John
ID : 221223
Date : 23.02.2018
Job: job1

User name : Andrew
ID : 378292
Date : 12.08.2017
Job: job2

User name : Chris
ID : 930712
Date : 05.11.2016
Job : job3

some random text
```

And this class:

```
class User
{
   public string UserName { get; set; }
   public string ID { get; set; }
   public string Date { get; set; }
   public string Job { get; set; }
   public User(string _UserName, string _ID, string _Date, string _Job)
   {
       UserName = _UserName
       ID = _ID;
       Date = _Date;
       Job = _Job;
   }
}
```

And I want to create a List of Users with informations from that string.

I have tried doing that:

```
   List<User> Users = new List<User>();

    string Data = (the data above)
    string[] lines = Data.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    List<string> UserNames = new List<string>();
    List<string> IDs = new List<string>();
    List<string> Dates = new List<string>();
    List<string> Jobs = new List<string>();

    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        if (line.StartsWith("User name : "))
        {
            UserNames.Add(Line.Remove(0, 12));                 
        }

        if (Line.StartsWith("ID : "))
        {
            IDs.Add(Line.Remove(0, 5));
        }

        if (Line.StartsWith("Date : "))
        {
           Dates.Add(Line.Remove(0, 7));
        }

        if (Line.StartsWith("Job : "))
        {
           Jobs.Add(Line.Remove(0, 6));
        }        
    }
    var AllData = UserNames.Zip(IDs, (u, i) => new { UserName = u, ID = i });

    foreach (var data in AllData)
    {
        Users.Add(new User(data.UserName, data.ID, "date", "job"));
    }
```

But I can only combine two lists using this code. Also, I have more than 4 values for each user (the string above was just a short example) .

Is there a better method? Thanks.

Comment: is the string is in withing json format?

Comment: No, it is just plain text. You can see the example above.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @asfdev991.  Please remember to add extra information about the question into the question itself so that future readers don't have to trawl the comments to find it ;)

Comment: do you read it from a file? is there always this empty line between the entries?

Comment: Yes, there is always a empty line between the entries. And the string also has other text in it, so I should ignore it. I have updated the question.

Comment: I edited my post, you can skip the header by searching for the key word with which the data starts. Have a look

Comment: Is it `User name :` or `User name:`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since it seems to be always 4 lines of information you could go in steps of `4` with a loop through the splitted array `lines`. At each step you would split by colon `:` and collect the last item, which is the desired value:

EDIT: In this case I would suggets to look for the START of the data.

```
int startIndex = Data.IndexOf("User name");
```

EDIT 2:

> also ends with another line of text

then you can use [LastIndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_LastIndexOf_System_String_) to find the end of the important information:

```
int endIndex = Data.LastIndexOf("Job");
int lengthOfLastLine = Data.Substring(endIndex).IndexOf(Environment.NewLine);
endIndex += lengthOfLastLine;
```

and then simply take a [SubString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_) from the startindex on until the end

```
string [] lines = Data.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex)
                     .Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
List<User> allUsers = new List<UserQuery.User>();

for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i += 4)
{
    string name = lines[i].Split(':').Last().Trim();
    string ID   = lines[i + 1].Split(':').Last().Trim();
    string Date = lines[i + 2].Split(':').Last().Trim();
    string Job  = lines[i + 3].Split(':').Last().Trim();
    allUsers.Add(new User(name, ID, Date, Job));
}
```

Ahhh, and you should `Trim` the spaces away. 
This solution should be readable. The hard coded step size of `4` is actually annoying in my solution

Disclaimer: This solution works only as long as the format does not change. If the order of the lines should change, it will return false results

Comment: Great idea. I prefer `Remove` to `Split()` though.

Comment: With semicolon it is the same as [.csv format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)

Comment: I forgot to say that the string also ends with another line of text (you can see the updated example in the question). In reality, each entry has 7 lines (not 4 as I said above), so I have changed "i +=4" to "i+=7" and I have added the remaining string (until string ExString  = lines[i + 6].Split(':').Last().Trim();) but now I get "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Comment: @asfdev991 something else  you forgot to say ? ;) hehe ok, there is a method: [LastIndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_LastIndexOf_System_String_) actually you should have enough information to fix it on your own now ;) You can use it to calculate the real endIndex then take this overload of [SubString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_) and get only the important part

Comment: @asfdev991 no problem. Welcome to StackOverflow. The best way to thank here is to [mark the answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) did you manage to find the real endIndex ?

Comment: Yes, I have fixed the issue.

Comment: @asfdev991 I made a second edit to get the endIndex. Have a look. Glad to hear that you have fixed it

Answer (score 3):

Instead of checking each line to add each of them to a a list, you can create your list of User directly. There you go:

1. Split by double new line
2. Split by new line
3. Build each User

Code:

```
var users = data.Split(new[] {"\n\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Select(lines =>
{
    var line = lines.Split(new[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    return new User(line[0].Substring(11), line[1].Substring(4), line[2].Substring(6), line[3].Substring(5));
});
```

[Try it online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yn8udb)

As @Mong Zhu answer, remove everything before and after. A this point, this is another question I wont try to solve. Remove the noise before and after then parse your data.

Comment: The 3rd record (for "chris") is different from the rest

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

The CSV format seems to be what you're looking for (since you want to add some header to this file the actual CSV stars on 6th line):

```
random text 12234
another random text 

User infos: 

UserName;ID;Date;Job
John;221223;23.02.2018;job1
Andrew;378292;12.08.2017;job2
Chris;930712;05.11.2016;job3
```

And then you could read this file and parse it:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("pathToFile");
var dataStartIndex = lines.IndexOf("UserName;ID;Date;Job");
var Users = lines.Skip(dataStartIndex + 1).Select(s =>
{
   var splittedStr = s.Split(';');
   return new User(splittedStr[0], splittedStr[1], splittedStr[2], splittedStr[3]);
}).ToList();
```

If you're working with console entry just skip the header part and let user enter comma separated values for each user on a different string. Parse it in a same way:

```
var splittedStr = ReadLine().Split(';');
var userToAdd = new User(splittedStr[0], splittedStr[1], splittedStr[2] , splittedStr[3]);
Users.Add(userToAdd);
```

Comment: `new User().ToList()` wont work. Also, you dont need it if `users` doesnt need to be a list.

Comment: The string above is not in the CSV format. It looks more like a INI file, but with a ":"

Comment: Yup, it's CSV-like file, sorry for typos, I've corrected them

Answer (score 2):

For a robust, flexible and self-documenting solution that will allow you to easily add new fields, ignore all the extraneous text and also cater for variations in your file format (this seems to be the case with, for example, no space in "ID:" only in the 3rd record), I would use a `Regex` and some LINQ to return a collection of records as follows:

```
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    public class Record
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string Job { get; set; }
    }
    public List<Record> Test()
    {
        string s = @"User name : John
        ID : 221223
        Date : 23.02.2018
        Job: job1

        User name : Andrew
        ID : 378292
        Date : 12.08.2017
        Job: job2

        User name : Chris
        ID: 930712
        Date : 05.11.2016
        Job: job3
        ";
        Regex r = new Regex(@"User\sname\s:\s(?<name>\w+).*?ID\s:\s(?<id>\w+).*?Date\s:\s(?<date>[0-9.]+).*?Job:\s(?<job>\w\w+)",RegexOptions.Singleline);
        r.Matches(s);
        return (from Match m in r.Matches(s)
                 select new Record
                 {
                     Name = m.Groups["name"].Value,
                     ID = m.Groups["id"].Value,
                     Date = m.Groups["date"].Value,
                     Job = m.Groups["job"].Value
                 }).ToList();
    }
```